# App Crashes when accessing component's setter (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I wrote the code base on Apple's example,
somehow the app will crash if accessing the setter of the custom entity component (the reveal() method)

I tried to initialize the component to see what will happen, but it crashed at anchor.addChild(card) (ViewController line 89) instead.
But it runs without any problem on iPadOS 14 which makes it even weirder.

Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix it?

my code

```
//  CardEntity.swift
//  Card-Game
//
//  Created by Ian Liu on 2020/7/21.
//

import Foundation
import RealityKit

class CardEntity: Entity, HasModel, HasCollision {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.components[ModelComponent] = ModelComponent(
            mesh: .generateBox(width: 0.09, height: 0.005, depth: 0.09),
                    materials: [SimpleMaterial(
                                    color: .orange,
                                    isMetallic: false)
                    ]
                )
    }
    var card: CardComponent {
        get { components[CardComponent] ?? CardComponent() }
        set { components[CardComponent] = newValue }
    }
}

extension CardEntity {
    func reveal() {
        card.revealed = true
        var transform = self.transform
        transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: 0, axis: [1, 0, 0])
        move(to: transform, relativeTo: parent, duration: 0.25, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
    }
    func hide() {
        card.revealed = false
        var transform = self.transform
        transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [1, 0, 0])
        move(to: transform, relativeTo: parent, duration: 0.25, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
    }
}
```

```
//  CardComponent.swift
//  Card-Game
//
//  Created by Ian Liu on 2020/7/21.
//

import Foundation
import RealityKit

struct CardComponent: Component, Codable {
    var revealed = false
    var id = -1
    init() {
        self.revealed = false
        self.id = -1
    }
}
```

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Card-Game
//
//  Created by 劉學逸 on 7/16/20.
//

import UIKit
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let cardCount = 16
    var prevCard: CardEntity? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.center = self.view.center
        arView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        arView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        arView.session.delegate = self
        
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentation) {
            config.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
        }
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        
        arView.session.run(config)
        addCoachingOverlay()
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal, minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2])
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        
        
        CardComponent.registerComponent()
        var cards: [CardEntity] = []
        var models: [Entity] = []
        for index in 1...cardCount {
            let cardModel = CardEntity()
            cardModel.name = "card_\((index+1)/2)"
            cardModel.card.id = (index+1)/2
            
            cards.append(cardModel)
        }
        
        
        var cancellable: Cancellable? = nil
        // will build for a long time if load 8 models
        cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_1")
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_2"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_3"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_4"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_5"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_6"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_7"))
            .append(ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "memory_card_8"))
            .collect().sink(receiveCompletion: {error in
                print("error: \(error)")
                cancellable?.cancel()},
                            receiveValue: { entities in
                                for (index, entity) in entities.enumerated() {
                                    entity.setScale(SIMD3<Float>(0.0025,0.0025,0.0025), relativeTo: anchor)
                                    entity.position = entity.position + SIMD3<Float>(0, 0.0025, 0)
                                    entity.name = "memory_card_\(index)"
                                    for _ in 1...2 {
                                        models.append(entity.clone(recursive: true))
                                    }
                                }
                                for (index, card) in cards.enumerated() {
                                    card.addChild(models[index])
                                }
                                cards.shuffle()
                                for card in cards {
                                    var flipTransform = card.transform
                                    flipTransform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [1, 0, 0])
                                    card.move(to: flipTransform, relativeTo: card.parent)
                                }
                                
                                //attach cards to the anchor
                                for (index, card) in cards.enumerated() {
                                    card.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                                    let x = Float(index % Int(sqrt(Double(self.cardCount)))) - 1.5
                                    let z = Float(index / Int(sqrt(Double(self.cardCount)))) - 1.5
                                    card.position = [x * 0.1, 0, z * 0.1]
                                    anchor.addChild(card)
                                }
                                cancellable?.cancel()
            })
        // Adding Occlusion Box
        // Create box mesh, 0.7 meters on all sides
        let boxSize: Float = 0.7
        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: boxSize)
        // Create Occlusion Material
        let material = OcclusionMaterial()
        // Create ModelEntity using mesh and materials
        let occlusionBox = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [material])
        // Position box with top slightly below game board
        occlusionBox.position.y = -boxSize / 2 - 0.001
        
        // Add to anchor
        anchor.addChild(occlusionBox)
    }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        arView.center = view.center
        centerCoachingView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let configuration = arView.session.configuration else { return }
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        arView.session.pause()
    }
    
    @IBAction func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
        if let entity = arView.entity(at: tapLocation) {
            var card = entity
            if entity.name.hasPrefix("memory_card") {
                card = entity.parent!
            }
            guard let cardEntity = card as? CardEntity else { return }
            print("tapped card id: \(cardEntity.card.id)")
            if cardEntity.card.revealed  {
                return
            } else {
                cardEntity.reveal()
            }
            if let lastCard = prevCard {
                print("last card id: \(lastCard.card.id)")
                if lastCard.card.id != cardEntity.card.id {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        cardEntity.hide()
                        lastCard.hide()
                    }
                }
                self.prevCard = nil
            } else {
                print("last card id: N\\A")
                prevCard = cardEntity
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: ARCoachingOverlayViewDelegate {
    func addCoachingOverlay() {
        let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        coachingOverlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        coachingOverlay.center = view.center
        coachingOverlay.delegate = self
        coachingOverlay.session = arView.session
        coachingOverlay.goal = .horizontalPlane
        arView.addSubview(coachingOverlay)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            coachingOverlay.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            coachingOverlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            coachingOverlay.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            coachingOverlay.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        ])
        coachingOverlay.activatesAutomatically = true
    }
    //TODO: Fix coachingView won't center when first orientation change
    func centerCoachingView() {
        for subview in arView.subviews {
            if let coachingView = subview as? ARCoachingOverlayView {
                coachingView.center = self.view.center
            }
        }
    }
}
```